# Merge two records in pandas on basis of individual column trust

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have recently started working with Pandas (Python beginner). I am trying to merge two records from different IDs and create a final record which contains values for each column from the IDs I trust for each column.

```
df1:
ID   NAME     ADDRESS    PHONE
1    abc      street1     9999

df2:
ID   NAME     ADDRESS    PHONE
2    xyz      street2     8888

df_col_priority:
COLUMN   PRIORITY_BY_ID
NAME        1
ADDRESS     2
PHONE       2
```

So here, based on priority for each column for each id, I should get single output record as:

```
df_output:
NAME      ADDRESS    PHONE
abc       street2     8888
```

So basically I should get NAME from ID=1 and other 2 fields from ID=2.
Likewise, I have thousands of records, for which I will pick pair of two records by a logic and calculate the final output record using above method.

I am not able to think of a way to achieve this other than looping over each column for each dataframe, extracting priority and constructing new record column by column by concat. But I think this is pretty inefficient. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to get name from df1, and address and phone from df2? I think you'll need to provide bigger input and output samples for receiving an accurate answer.

Comment: Yes, I want to get name from ID=1 row and address, phone from ID=2 row, because priority for NAME is to pick from ID=1 and priority for address and phone is to pick from ID=2.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding your problem, but in any case, it seems like it might be useful to revisit how you are organizing your dataframes. That being said, this solution, inelegant though it may be, works in your case:

```
# start by concatenating df1 and df2 into one dataframe
full_df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
# create an empty output dataframe with the columns you want
df_output = pd.DataFrame(columns = df1.columns[1:])
# loop through your df_col_priority, making a series of your desired values,
# appending that series to df_output
# this uses a list iteration
df_output = df_output.append(pd.Series(
    [full_df.loc[full_df.ID == row.PRIORITY_BY_ID, row.COLUMN].values[0]
     for _, row in df_col_priority.iterrows()],
    index=df_col_priority.COLUMN), ignore_index=True)
```

Your `df_output` then looks like:

```
>>> df_output
  NAME  ADDRESS PHONE
0  abc  street2  8888
```

Comment: How do you suggest re-organizing the dataframes?

Comment: For starters, I would keep all your observations (trusted or no) in the same dataframe (I achieved that by in that first line `full_df = pd.concat([df1, df2])`, but it might be a pain or require a loop if you have a bunch of dataframes)